# Update Orchard Widget when button is pressed

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

I've created a simple orchard widget with an input field and button. I added the widget to my homepage.

I have created a Controller and when I press the button, I call a function in the controller that returns an ActionResult.

So I have:
InfoWidget.cshtml
InfoWidgetController.cs that has public ActionResult ButtonPressed().

All I want the code to do is update the widget (not the whole page) with something like "Thanks for the button press!"

So here are my questions:

1. What do I return as the ActionResult? I don't know how to get it to stay on the homepage and not redirect somewhere. If I call something like Index(), I get an error because Orchard can't find Index. Should I create a new Index page and set that as the homepage?
2. How do I update my widget with some sort message?

Comment: This is not really Orchard-specific. Seems like you need to learn how to create and handle Ajax requests in ASP.NET MVC. You should Google it, you'll find plenty of examples.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in that direction. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Dont know about that. Tried myself yesterday. add [Themed] to the controller. and not redirected.